# React native code visibility

Tags: react-native

Currently I'm developing an react-native-app, and am very happy with this framework.

My question is this: 
When you develop an hybrid-app, like Ionic for example, the code is visible 
via the chrome-dev-tool.

Is this also possible for an react-native-app, or is my code safe? I have a few important data in my code, which should be secret :-)

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should assume that any code being run on a system under the control of another person is visible to that person.  If he has the skills to understand your code, he certainly has the skills to dig it out.